# Golang template variable

Tags: go-templates

This is my first stab at doing front end with Go.
I have this template:

```
{{define "index"}}{{template "_header.html"}}
{{template "_message.html"}}
<div>Page Index</div>
<div>Welcome {{.Title}}</div>    
{{template "_footer.html"}}     
{{end}}
```

Where the `{{.Title}}` works as expected.

But when I attempt to use it in an include file `{template "_header.html"}` it fails.

```
{{define "_header.html"}}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/css.css"/>
        <title>{{.Title}}</title>
    </head><body>{{end}}
```

Now the `<title>` tag is empty.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the template documentation the use of `{{ template "name" }}` passes nil data to your template. Thus, there is no data to render into `{{ .Title }}`. You need to use `{{ template "name" pipeline }}` to pass your data into the included template.

In your case `{{ template "_header.html" . }}` should do the trick, by passing the current data object into your included template.

See [`template` documentation here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

```
{{template "name"}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.

{{template "name" pipeline}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
    to the value of the pipeline.
```